# Update file's last modified time when copied via grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am copying a file with [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy). I have another task which attempts to determine if a file should be copied based on the file's last modified timestamp. Copying the file does not update that timestamp, but I would like it to.

What's a simple way to force a file to update without actually changing the contents of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [grunt-touch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-touch) is the solution with the `mtime: true` option set.

```
touch: {
  options: {
    mtime: true
  },
  src: ['foo/example.js']
}
```